# Does logical short-circuiting not work with if-constexpr?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, constexpr

With normal `if` condition, short circuiting works.

However with an attempted short circuit for if-constexpr doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename ... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    std::string a; 
    // for the call of foo, sizeof...(args) = 0, so a > 2 shouldn't be evaluated.
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 0 || a > 2) {
        std::cout << "ASD" << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
   foo();
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FpllpLq0ixwHhPPP)

Edit:
Seems like lots of comments are bit off of what I was attempting.
I will just quote @chris comment:

> People seem to be missing the point, so here's a better example of why
>   this is useful:
>
> ```
> if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) > 0 && is_integral_v<first_t<Ts...>>) { 
>     /* corresponding logic */ 
> }
> ```
>
> Currently, this requires nested constexpr ifs

It seems this is not currently possible and only workaround is just write nested ifs.

Comment: how do you know if `a>2` gets evaluated?

Comment: @tobi303 I have added a demo where it fails in compilation.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Why do you think `a>2` gets evaluated?

Comment: @melpomene By evaluated I mean it gets compiled. If the first condition passes then the second one should get ignored in compilation itself because that's how logical short-circuiting works.

Comment: No, that's not how short-circuiting works. It doesn't just get ignored during compilation; it still needs to be valid code.

Comment: @themagicalyang - typechecking is not the same as evaluation. You don't need to know the value of `a` to know it is a `std::string`, not a number.

Comment: `a > 2` doesn't compile. Do you expect to be able to write `constexpr if (true || oh look, ponies!!!11!!eleven!)`?

Comment: People seem to be missing the point, so here's a better example of why this is useful: `if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) > 0 && is_integral_v<first_t<Ts...>>) { /* corresponding logic */ }`. Currently, this requires nested constexpr ifs.

Comment: @chris Yes. That's a good example. i.e if sizeof > 0 fails don't even attempt to evaluate second part of or. But this doesn't work, even though it seems useful. It seems as of now, I would have to write lots of nested ifs.

Comment: In fairness, I've rarely had a use for this, particularly since the second part could often benefit from extracting the offending piece (`first_t<Ts...>`) into a separate "variable" (type alias) so that it can be used in both the condition and logic without repetition. Extending short-circuit evaluation to a compile-time equivalent would be useful, but not too commonly, and a nested check isn't particularly bad like nested tag dispatching usually was.

Comment: @chris Actually I am finding lots of usage for such because of a variable which can be both be a constexpr int or a constexpr struct-object. My condition was like `if (type_is_struct or int_value > 0) { /** do something*/ }`.

Comment: "Seems like lots of comments are bit off of what I was attempting" ... possibly because the example in your question made no sense, which is why the comments/answers you were receiving are about it not making sense. We can't intuit what you *actually* meant.

Answer (score 5):

The expression `a > 2` needs to be syntactically and semantically valid, because otherwise, the compiler cannot rule out that it would return some type for which the `||` operator is overloaded. Only the built-in `||` operator has short-circuiting behaviour.

However, the expression `a > 2` would not be evaluated. You can verify this by changing `std::string a` to `int a` (left uninitialised): evaluation of the expression `a > 2` would have undefined behaviour, and therefore evaluation of `a > 2` is not permitted in constant expressions.

Answer (score 4):

While the condition might not be evaluated, your program doesn't compile because it is invalid – you can't compare a `string` and an `int`. You would get similar results if you put random characters in the second operand of the `||`.

Comment: Buy they are inside a if-constexpr block so shouldn't the second argument to operator|| not get compiled at all due to short-circuiting?

Comment: @themagicalyang The compiler still needs to parse the program. It knows `a` is of type `std::string` and needs to know what operator it has to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use short-circuit form in `if constexpr`, but please notice, this may performs differently with runtime `if`. Consider the following example:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5hffP11re)

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr auto foo(T const& val)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
    {
        if constexpr (T{} < 1)
            return val * 2;
    }
    return val;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto bar(T const& val)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T> && T{} < 1)
        return val * 2;
    else
        return val;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr char const* x = "hello";
    static_assert(foo(5) == 5 * 2);
    static_assert(foo(x) == x);

    static_assert(bar(5) == 5 * 2);
    //static_assert(bar(x) == x);  // ERROR, not compile

    return 0;
}
```

The `foo` will compile with both `int` and `char const*` while `bar` not, and because `std::is_integral_v<T> && T{} < 1` in `bar` is instantiated as a whole.

So you'd better NOT short-circuit `if constexpr` to avoid this unexpected behavior.